# Unregister Nav Menu from Child-Theme

Tags: menus, user-registration, filters

I like to use the [Starkers Theme](http://nathanstaines.com/articles/starkers-html5/) and build child-theme.

So, I`d like to remove the this primary menu

Starkers (functions.php)

```
function starkers_setup() {
// This theme uses wp_nav_menu() in one location.
register_nav_menus( array(
'primary' => __( 'Primary Navigation', 'starkers' ),
) );


}
endif;
```

My child-theme functions.php looks like this:

```
unregister_nav_menu( array(
'primary' => __( 'Primary Navigation', 'starkers' ),
));

// my new nav
register_nav_menus(array(
'primary_navigation' => __('Main', 'starkers'),
'utility_navigation' => __('Meta', 'starkers')
));
```

But it doesn´t  work for me.

What´s wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Starkers theme setup is hooked to `after_setup_theme`, at a priority of `10`. So you basically have to wrap the unregister function inside another function (child themes functions.php file) and add it *later* than the parent themes setup function, so it gets first added by the parent and later on removed by the child.

```
function wpse_remove_parent_theme_locations()
{
    // @link http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/unregister_nav_menu
    unregister_nav_menu( 'primary' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpse_remove_parent_theme_locations', 20 );
```

Answer (score 2):

This should definitely work for you, I just checked out

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'remove_default_menu', 11 );
function remove_default_menu(){
unregister_nav_menu('primary');
}
```

Comment: Check the edited code, this should work.

Answer (score 0):

The other solutions didn't work for me.

This one worked:

```
function remove_parent_theme_locations()
{
    unregister_nav_menu( 'primary' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'remove_parent_theme_locations', 20 );
```

Comment: The point being it needed to be on the init hook instead? That might vary depending on your theme, and I'd guess this means your theme has hooked init to register the menu rather than after_setup_theme which is usual.